# ViewSet and additional retrieve URL

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a django model `Donation` that I expose as a ViewSet. Now I want to add an additional URL to a second model `Shop` where a related instance of `Donation` can be retrieved via the parameter `order_id` and custom actions can be executed.

```
# models.py
class Donation(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  order_id = models.StringField(help_text='Only unique in combination with field `origin`')
  origin = models.ForeignKey('Shop', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Shop(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  

# views.py
class DonationViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                     mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                     mixins.ListModelMixin,
                     viewsets.GenericViewSet):

  def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):  
    if kwargs['pk'].isdigit():
      return super(DonationViewSet, self).retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
      shop_id = self.request.query_params.get('shop_id', None)
      order_id = self.request.query_params.get('order_id', None)
      
      if shop_id is not None and order_id is not None:
        instance = Donations.objects.filter(origin=shop_id, order_id=order_id).first()
        if instance is None:
          return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        
        return Response(self.get_serializer(instance).data)

      return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

  @action(methods=['post'], detail=True)
  def custom_action(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      pass

class ShopViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  pass

# urls.py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'donations', DonationViewSet)
router.register(r'shops', ShopViewSet)
router.register(r'shops/(?P<shop_id>[0-9]+)/donations/(?P<order_id>[0-9]+)', DonationViewSet)
```

My goal is to have http://localhost:8000/donations point at the entire DonationViewSet. Also I would like to lookup an individual donation, by its combination of `shop_id` and `order_id` like follows http://localhost:8000/shops/123/donations/1337/ and also executing the custom action like follows http://localhost:8000/shops/123/donations/1337/custom_action/. The problem I have is that the second url returns an entire queryset, not just a single instance of the model.

Comment: You're registering the same viewset twice, that doesn't make sense. With DRF you don't separately register unique URLs, the router does that behind the scenes.

Comment: Thank you @AKX. I suspected this might be the case, because it really felt like I was working against DRF here.
What would be the DRF way of doing this, instead? Plain `View`s, not `ViewSet`s?

Comment: Do you want to serach by order_id in your shop page ?? Is it ?

Comment: @boyenec Yes, but no :D

I want to search a shop's donations by `order_id` and then change them. I use this route so that a shop can update a donation without first retrieving its `id`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use [drf-nested-routers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#drf-nested-routers), which will have something like this:

```
from rest_framework_nested import routers

from django.conf.urls import url

# urls.py
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'donations', DonationViewSet, basename='donations')
router.register(r'shops', ShopViewSet, basename='shops')

shop_donations_router = routers.NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'', lookup='shops')
shop_donations_router.register(
    r'donations', ShopViewSet, basename='shop-donations'
)

# views.py
class ShopViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None, donations_pk=None):
        # pk for shops, donations_pk for donations

    @action(detail=True, methods=['PUT'])
    def custom_action(self, request, pk=None, donations_pk=None):
        # pk for shops, donations_pk for donations
```

This is not tested! But in addition to what you already have, this will support:

```
donations/
donations/1337/
shops/123/donations/1337/
shops/123/donations/1337/custom_action
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add urls by simply appending to the router's urls in the config like so. If all you want to do is add a single action from a view for one specifc url, and dont need all of the actions/urls for the viewset

```py
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('some_path', my_lookup_view)),
] # typical django url convention
urlpatterns += router.urls

# views.py
@api_view(['POST'])
def my_looup_view(request, shop_id, order_id):
    # ...some lookup...
    pass
```

Comment: For future readers: This is a very good solution and works flawlessly. I had implemented it, but then decided to restructure my urls entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to

- derive from `GenericViewSet` since you're using models anyway
- override `get_object()` instead with your custom lookup logic:

```
from rest_framework import mixins
from rest_framework.generics import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.viewsets import GenericViewSet


class MyModelViewSet(
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    GenericViewSet,
):
    def get_object(self):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        lookup_value = self.kwargs["pk"]
        if lookup_value.isdigit():
            obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=lookup_value)
        else:
            obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, third_party_service_id=lookup_value)

        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
        return obj

    @action(methods=["post"], detail=True)
    def custom_action(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        thing = self.get_object()


# urls.py
router.register(r"mymodels", MyModelViewSet)
```

This should let you do

- `mymodels/` to list models,
- `mymodels/123/` to get a model by PK,
- `mymodels/kasjdfg/` to get a model by third-party service id,
- `mymodels/123/custom_action/` to run `custom_action` on a model by PK
- `mymodels/kasjdfg/custom_action/` to run `custom_action` on a model by service id,

Comment: I added the missing mixin to my sample code, I forgot that as I simplified my actual code. Your answer *almost* looks like what I want, but instead of `mymodels/kasjdfg/custom_action/`, I would like the URL to be `myothermodel/kasjdfg/custom_action/`. Is that possible using the DRF? Ditching the `ViewSet` for this class would be an option for me, if that gives me more control over things like these. This really is the central model for my application.

Comment: Why would you have two URLs to access the same models with?

Comment: Because the `third_party_service_id` relates to `myothermodel` and not `mymodel`. To make matters worse, it is only guaranteed to be unique for a given `myothermodel`. I simplified my example, because I didn't think it would add to my question, but the real URL would have to be `myothermodels/123/mymodels/kasdfg/custom_action`. I know that I could easily solve this with two requests, but this is a route that will be called thousands of times per day, so I would like to cut traffic in half, if possible.

Comment: You didn't mention a `myothermodel` before?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the other model in my first try, because I wanted to provide a very generic question. I have reworked my question to better reflect my actual models and hope the new model names help understand their relation better.